# Writing a proof

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am stuck at showing how if:

$P \rightarrow Q$ then this implies ($Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)$

I know that if we assume $P$ is true then $Q$ also must be true. 
Therefore if $Q$ is true then $R$ must be true. And because $Q$ is true because $P$ is true so therefore $R$ must also be true.

However it would be appreciated if someone could help me understand this why is the case and what proof technique it is.

Comment: What is "R"?  "P=> Q" says nothing about "R"!  "P=> Q" does NOT say "if Q is true then R must be true".  The conclusion says that "IF Q being true implies that some other statement R is true then P being true also implies that this "R" is true.

Comment: Well because P is true Q must be true. Then we have Q => R and we know Q is true from previous assumption so therefore R is true. If R is true because of Q and Q is true because of P then R also must be true because of P

Comment: This statement would have different proofs in different logical theories. In the theory you've been studying, do connectives like $\rightarrow$ represent a valuation on mappings of the letters to "true" and "false"? Try a truth table, or maybe a reduction tree. Or are the connectives more abstract, and just symbols that appear in axioms? You'd need a sequence of formulae where each can be proved from previous and/or from the axioms.

Answer (score 13):

This property is called *transitivity* of implication.

You pretty much gave a proof in your question, but here's a proof written out in slightly more precise terms.

Suppose $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true. To prove $(Q \Rightarrow R) \Rightarrow (P \Rightarrow R)$, you need to assume $Q \Rightarrow R$ and derive $P \Rightarrow R$. So assume that $Q \Rightarrow R$ is true. To prove $P \Rightarrow R$ is true, you need to assume $P$ is true and derive $R$. So assume $P$ is true. All we have to do now is prove that $R$ is true.

At this point, we're assuming that $P \Rightarrow Q$, $Q \Rightarrow R$ and $P$ are all true. So:

- Since $P$ and $P \Rightarrow Q$ are true, we have that $Q$ is true; and
- Since $Q$ and $Q \Rightarrow R$ are true, we have that $R$ is true.

So we're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can also prove this somewhat verbosely with a truth table... (I have named my intermediate steps just because the table was too wide to display nicely.)

$$
\begin{array}{|c c c|c|c|c|c|c|}
P & Q & R & P \implies Q & Q \implies R & P \implies R &  & \\
 & & &A&B&C&B \implies C & A \implies (B \implies C) \\
\\
T & T & T & T & T & T & T & T\\
T & T & F & T & F & F & T & T\\
T & F & T & F & T & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & T & F & F & T\\
F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T\\
F & T & F & T & F & T & T & T\\
F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T\\
F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want a conceptual proof, you just need to know how to prove an implication. How do you prove $A\rightarrow B$? Assume $A$ is true, then show that $B$ follows (hoping you have some other information laying around to do this using $A$.

- Step 1 To show:
  $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow ((Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R))$,
  assume $(P \rightarrow Q)$ and show $(Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)$.
- step 2 To show $(Q \rightarrow R) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)$, assume  $Q \rightarrow R$ and then show $P \rightarrow R$.
- step 3 To show $P \rightarrow R$, assume $P$ and then show $R$.

At each stage we're assuming something so by this last step we've assumed a whole bunch that can help us to show $R$.

Using $P$, assumed true from the last step and $P\rightarrow Q$ assumed true from step 1, $Q$ follows, via modus ponens.

Using this $Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$ assumed true from step 2, $R$ follows, again via modus ponens.

And we're done. In short, a chain of implications unraveled from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a sort of transitivity. $P\implies Q$ is true. So if $Q\implies R$, then $P\implies Q\implies R$. I don’t think there is a name for this. It’s just multiple implications that give a result.

Proving this is simple. Given $Q\implies R$, we want to demonstrate $P\implies R$.
So let’s suppose that $P$ is true. So, $Q$ is true by $(P\implies Q)$ (it’s called the “Modus ponens”). But $Q$ is true, so $R$ is true. 
QED.

Answer (score 0):

$A\Rightarrow B$ can be written as $\neg A\vee B.$ Therefore,
$$
(Q\Rightarrow R)\Rightarrow(P\Rightarrow R) \\
=\neg(\neg Q\vee R)\vee (\neg P\vee R) \\
= (Q \wedge \neg R)\vee (\neg P\vee R) \\
= (\neg P \vee Q\vee R)\wedge (\neg P \vee R \vee \neg R) \\
= (\neg P \vee Q\vee R) \\
= (\neg P \vee Q)\vee R \\
= (P\Rightarrow Q) \vee R
$$